# Determining the projections onto the Horizontal and Vertical Space

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, projection-matrices

I am looking at a map $\Pi: GL(n)\mapsto Sym^+(n)$ via $\Pi(A)=AA^T$.
This has differential $d\Pi_A(Z)=ZA^T+AZ^T$.

The vertical space $\mathcal{V}_A$ is the kernel of $d\Pi_A$, and so
$$Z\in\mathcal{V_A}\iff Z^T=-A^{-1}ZA^T.$$

With the inner product $G(Z,W)=tr(Z^TW)$, the horizontal space $\mathcal{H}_A$ is the orthogonal complement to the Vertical space. 
We have a defining property for $\mathcal{H}_A$ which is 
$$W\in\mathcal{H}_A\iff Z^T=A^TZA^{-1}.$$

I am able to prove, this but not in a satisfying way (Go right to left and then by dimensions being equal they must define the same sets), so seeing how this relationship is derived would be helpful.

My big hang up is that I can't figure out what the projections onto these subspaces look like. Thanks.

Comment: First things first: Write the equation characterizing $\mathcal H_A$ with $W$'s in it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $Z\in\mathcal V_A \iff AZ^\top$ is skew-symmetric. With respect to the standard inner product you've given on $n\times n$ matrices, the orthogonal complement of the subspace of skew-symmetric matrices is the subspace of symmetric matrices.

Since $\mathcal V_A$ is the set of all matrices $Z$ so that $AZ^\top$ is skew-symmetric, we see that $\mathcal H_A$ must be the set of all matrices $W$ so that $WA^{-1}$ is symmetric. We know that $\langle AZ^\top,S\rangle = 0$ for all symmetric matrices $S$, and so $0 = \langle Z^\top,A^\top S \rangle = \langle Z,SA\rangle$. Thus $(\mathcal V_A)^\perp = \{W: WA^{-1} \text{ is symmetric}\}$.

You can easily give a (sadly, non-orthogonal) basis for $\mathcal H_A$ by multiplying the obvious orthonormal basis for the subspace of symmetric  matrices on the right by $A$. Similarly, you obtain a basis for $\mathcal V_A$ by multiplying the obvious orthonormal basis for the subspace of skew-symmetric matrices on the right by $(A^\top)^{-1}$.

Given $X$ and $A$, to find the decomposition $X=Z+W$ with $Z\in\mathcal V_A$ and $W\in\mathcal H_A$, we can solve the equations
\begin{align*}
XA^\top + AX^\top &= WA^\top + AW^\top \\
W^\top &= A^\top W A^{-1}
\end{align*}
as a monster system of linear equations for $W$:
$$WA^\top + AA^\top W A^{-1} = AX^\top + XA^\top.$$

Comment: I don't see how $Z\in\mathcal{V}_A\iff AZ$ is skew. From $ZA^T+AZ^T=0$, we get that $ZA^T=-AZ^T$, so $ZA^T$ is skew and that $A^{-1}Z$ is skew.

Comment: I see how to get the determining equation for $\mathcal{H}_A$ relationship from manipulating the i.p. Thanks.

Comment: Oops. I have edited.

Comment: Great thanks for the edit. Should I assume that maybe there isn't a nice projection? The author of the paper I am reading changes coordinates so that $d\Pi_A(Z)=ZA^{-1}$ for $Z\in\mathcal{H}_A$ and I am not exactly sure how they did that, and this was part of me trying to work out all the details.

Comment: Even in the case $A=I$, we just happen to "know" how to write a matrix as the sum of a symmetric and a skew-symmetric matrix, but it effectively comes from solving the same system of equations. :) How does the inner product transform under the author's change of coordinates?

Comment: With $G$ as before, the metric on the target space becomes $g_{\Pi}(d\Pi(Z),d\Pi(W_)=G(Z_H,W_H)$ and the they write $g_V(X,Y)=G(XV^{1/2},YV^{1/2})=tr(XVY)$